# Xcode wants to access "Xcode-AlternateDSID" in keychain

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode9beta6

When I start Xcode, I now get the message 'Xcode wants to access "Xcode-AlternateDSID" in keychain'.

What does that mean? Should I accept?

Comment: Which version of Xcode is this?

Comment: Version 9.0 beta 6 (9M214v)

Comment: I have 9.1, not beta, and get the same problem. Using macOS 10.13.1.

Comment: any updates on this??

Comment: This still occurs in Xcode 11.5 and is immediately followed by a similar message for access to "Xcode-Token". Don't forget to click "Always Allow" otherwise it will ask every time you open Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

So it's asking for your keychain login password — which *may* be the same as your computer login, or not. I ended up changing my keychain login password, but it accepted my computer login as valid. [Here's some info on keychain login password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201609), [here's some info on how to reset that](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860).